# How can I group issues in the VS Code GitHub Issues and Pull Requests extension?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How do I create a query for the [GitHub Issues and Pullrequests](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github) extension for VS Code that groups the found issues by milestone?

Example queries that come with the extension are for example:

```json
"githubIssues.queries": [
    {
      "label": "My Issues (Open)",
      "query": "default"
    },
    {
      "label": "Created Issues (Open)",
      "query": "author:${user} state:open repo:${owner}/${repository} sort:created-desc"
    },
```

now the first one groups the issues exactly like I want it:

[image]

But it **only shows my** issues. Now I want a similar query but regardless of the assignee.
I tried this:

```
{
  "label": "test (Open)",
  "query": "state:open repo:${owner}/${repository}"
},
```

but this only shows all issues in the correct repository but without the grouping by milestones.

The vscode extension [GitHub Issues and Pullrequests](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github) claims to use the [github search syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax) for this, but I cannot really figure out how milestones can be retreived by that and how this would be incorporated into the extension specific settings. What you can do though, is to filter issues by a milestone, but in that case you have to know the name/sting in beforehand. I rather would like to have a listing.

Comment: Oh, I have just seen that there is a feature request for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/issues/1881

Answer (score 2):

This is the subject of a feature request for the `vscode-pull-request-github` extension: [Provide group by setting for queries #1881](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/issues/1881). The issue is completed by PR [Provide group by setting for queries #5632](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/pull/5632), which is to be released in the January 2024 release of the extension.

One of the examples given by Alex Ross in that issue ticket for proposed capabilities is like this:

> ```json
> {
>   "label": "Alex's Issues",
>   "query": "assignee:alexr00 state:open repo:Microsoft/vscode sort:updated-desc",
>   "groupby": "milestone"
> }
> ```

Another more advanced example given is this:

> ```json
> {
>   "label": "Alex's Issues",
>   "query": "assignee:alexr00 state:open sort:updated-desc",
>   "groupby": ["repo", "milestone"]
> }
> ```

Comment: yes, right. I saw that one actually a few minutes after my question.  Would be pretty easy to configure. Thanks for your input. I will definitely upvote this. Still, I wonder why this is implemented in the `default` query already and is not available as an option to other queries.